# Rerouting incoming packets from server to local machine B instead of A

Tags: iptables, tcp, iptables-redirect

I'm trying to redirect a server's incoming TCP packets to local machine B.

The application client on local machine A (`192.168.0.7`) is connected to the server (`1.2.3.4`), so every incoming TCP packet from the server arrives at local machine A on port 38xx.

1. How can I redirect the packets from the server to local machine B (`192.168.0.20`) instead of local machine A?
2. How can I then send the packets back to the server from local machine B but make it seem that it was coming from local machine A?

I have tried the following:

- Enabling port forwarding by editing the `sysctl.conf` file.
- Running the IP tables command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.7 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 38xx -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.120:38xx
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

However, analyzing the traffic with Wireshark doesn't seem to bring up any results.

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Forward Traffic: `[client] --> [proxy] --> [server-A] --> [server-B]`

Return Traffic: `[server-B] --> [server-A] --> [proxy] --> [client]`

If this is what your traffic flow should look like, then you have to configure `server-A` to forward and masquerade traffic. When `server-A` receives traffic from `proxy`, it will forward to `server-B`.

While `server-B` has an IP of `192.168.0.20`, let's assume the following on `server-A`:

```
eth0 is facing the proxy
eth1 is facing server-B
TCP 3800 is listening on server-A and server-B respectively
```

On `server-A`, do the following:

```
$ sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 3800 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.20:3800
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```